# In Active Record, how can I search for titles that start with an integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using a Postgres backend but it could in theory change to MySQL (or even, yes, MS SQL) so I'm looking for a generic example that works.

Say I have a column labeled "title" that contains video game titles.  If I want to query all of the ones that start with a number then I use:

```
Games.where("title LIKE '0%' OR title LIKE '1%' OR title LIKE '2%' OR title LIKE '3%' OR title LIKE '4%' OR title LIKE '5%' OR title LIKE '6%' OR title LIKE '7%' OR title LIKE '8%' OR title LIKE '9%'")
```

This certainly works and it will probably work across any RDMS but looks a little ugly.  Is there a better way using Rails/AR 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the powerful regular expressions.

```
Games.where("title REGEXP ?","^\\d")
```

More information: [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: Will this work with any backend SQL server?  Such as Postgres or maybe even MS SQL?  Because that doesn't look like valid MS SQL syntax.

Comment: The syntax for postgres is a little different: http://www.regular-expressions.info/postgresql.html

Comment: **Does not work for Postgres**; error: `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "REGEXP"`.

Comment: @Zorayr the same problem here: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "REGEXP"